# Angular ng set defaults to pug extension

Tags: angular, pug, angular-cli

In documentation(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) I can see that to create component via

`ng g c name`

with scss extension I need to

`ng set defaults.styleExt scss`

but what I can do to create component instead html extension with pug extension?

I tired this:

`ng set defaults.templateExt pug`

but this doesn't work

Comment: You can't. Angular CLI supports different stylesheets, but not different templates - [the blueprint](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/component/files/__path__) is for HTML.

Comment: Maybe avoid the cli, it is restrictive.